# Laravel 5.4 : Login and singup working on shared hosting but not on VPS server

Tags: laravel-5

I move the project from shared hosting to VPS hosting now everything working fine such as inner pages, design, image loading but I am unable to login and signup now.

When I submit the login/Signup form it will redirect to the same page but without any error message.

And I also generate the Token via command do I need to do anything more to make it work.

I also check the laravel.log file and other things but unable to solve this.

Can anybody face the same issue

Comment: With same code, it is working on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is I do not create the session folder to store the session of Laravel 5.4